# Different Constructors, Same Implementation

Tags: c#, casting

I have this class containing two constructors with different signatures but they do the same thing:

```
public Person(Dictionary dictionary, string someString)
    : base(dictionary, someString)
{
    base.GetProperty("FirstName");
    base.GetProperty("LastName");
}

public Person(Dictionary dictionary, string[] someStringArray)
    : base(dictionary, someStringArray)
{
    base.GetProperty("FirstName");
    base.GetProperty("LastName");
}
```

The type of the second parameter in each of these constructors determines the behavior of the 'GetProperty' method.

I've read about `casting` and the bad behaviors of it, but would it be appropriate to do something like  this:

```
public Person(Dictionary dictionary, Object something)
{
}
```

and then cast `something` to either a `string` or `string[]` depending on whichever is appropriate?

Comment: Why must there be 2 constructors? Why can't there be only one: `public Person(Dictionary dct, string[] something)`. Simpler, better for the client.

Comment: In theory yes, I could just use one `string[]` and if its `string` just pick `string[0]` But the behavior between processing `string` and `string[]` are different, also the determination of `string` and `string[]` is based elsewhere. The object itself does not determine if the parameter is a `string` or `string[]`. I guess this is very vague. Im trying to add in a better example.

Comment: _behavior between processing string and string[] are different_.  So `string[0]` is not the same thing/object/property as `string` in the other contractor, yes? How about optional parameters: `public  Person(Dictionary dict, string[] otherStuff, string Fname = null)`.

Comment: @radarbob I like the idea of optional parameter. I'll see if it makes sense to incorporate that in the scope of my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things your could do:

1. Refactor the common code into a method (like `Initialize`) and call that:

   ```
   private void Initialize()
   {
       base.GetProperty("FirstName");
       base.GetProperty("LastName");
   }

   public Person(Dictionary dictionary, string someString)
       : base(dictionary, someString)
   {
       Initialize();
   }

   public Person(Dictionary dictionary, string[] someStringArray)
       : base(dictionary, someStringArray)
   {
       Initialize();
   }
   ```
2. Not sure whether that's an option as I don't know how the behaviour changes but you could reduce one case to the other:

   ```
   public Person(Dictionary dictionary, string someString)
       : this(dictionary, new [] { someString })
   {
   }

   public Person(Dictionary dictionary, string[] someStringArray)
       : base(dictionary, someStringArray)
   {
       base.GetProperty("FirstName");
       base.GetProperty("LastName");
   }
   ```

Apart from that:

- I'd avoid the casting. Apparently only strings or arrays of strings make sense to be passed in. If you change the parameter to `object` then it is no longer clear to the caller what he can and cannot pass in and would have to write a test to make sure that what he is passing in will be accepted. It reduces the clarity of the interface.
- `GetProperty` seems to be a strange thing to call in a constructor. I'd expect it to return a property value yet you do nothing with the return value.
- Consider making "FirstName" and "LastName" (and any other property string you use) string constants rather than literals - especially if you use them in more than one place. [Lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711435/typesafe-notifypropertychanged-using-linq-expressions) might be an option if they are actual properties on the object.

Comment: In this case, both suggestions are OK, but generally I prefer the second one, because it allows me to use readonly modifier on fields. Further more, if the literals FirstName and LastName are used more then once in code, they should become as private static const string fields. Last but not least, if FirstName is the name of a property in base type, try to uses [lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728465/implementing-notifypropertychanged-without-magic-strings) (type safe) to select them.

Comment: @hichaeretaqua: Good points, although I suspect the properties are supplied via the dictionary in which case lambda expressions won't be an option. Just a guess though.

Comment: @ChrisWue Exactly!. The dictionary and the `string` or the `string[]` determines what `GetProperty` does.